# Many-to-many or one-to-many relationships between custom Magento models

Tags: magento, many-to-many, one-to-many

3 models mapping 3 tables: Image, Slider and SliderImageAssoc. In this case it's one-to-many, as one Image can be "linked" to many Sliders.

The ZF way, which I'm accustomed to, also proposes 3 models, and, with special internal data stored in them, you can do things like $imageRow->getSliderViaSliderImageAssoc(), resulting the parent row of Slider of that certain Image model.

My question is how exactly does one fetches related models in Magento? I've seen methods named `setParentFieldName`, but I don't think they were in core. Can you do things like:

```
foreach ($model->getCollection() as $model) {
  $parentRow       = $model->getParent('some/model/name');
  $dependentRowset = $model->getChildren('some/other/model/name');
}
```

PS: I don't necessarily want to use the ZF style of fetching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Magento there is no support for generic mapping of entity table relationships as far as I know. I suggest adding helper methods to the resource model and resource collection to add the joins to the select object if required.

Here is an examples from the core of the mentioned utility method approach to load additional data on a collection:

```
// from Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::joinUrlRewrite()
public function joinUrlRewrite()
{
    $this->joinTable(
        'core/url_rewrite',
        'entity_id=entity_id',
        array('request_path'),
        '{{table}}.type = ' . Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::TYPE_PRODUCT,
        'left'
    );

    return $this;
}
```

If called, the `core_url_rewrite` table is joined with the product entity table.

If the joined data needs to be loaded every time, the `_getLoadSelect()` method can be used for resource models, or `_initSelect()` for collections.
Here is an example for that from the `cms/page` resource model:

```
// from Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page::_getLoadSelect()
protected function _getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object)
{
    $select = parent::_getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object);

    if ($object->getStoreId()) {
        $storeIds = array(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID, (int)$object->getStoreId());
        $select->join(
            array('cms_page_store' => $this->getTable('cms/page_store')),
            $this->getMainTable() . '.page_id = cms_page_store.page_id',
            array())
            ->where('is_active = ?', 1)
            ->where('cms_page_store.store_id IN (?)', $storeIds)
            ->order('cms_page_store.store_id DESC')
            ->limit(1);
    }

    return $select;
}
```

An example for an `_initSelect()` join can be found in `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Stock_Item_Collection::_initSelect()` (I'll won't post it here because it is so similar to the `_getLoadSelect()` example).

Some modules set joins on collections from "outside" the module, i.e. the stock item collection `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Stock_Item::addCatalogInventoryToProductCollection($productCollection)`. Here the `cataloginventory` module uses the product collections select object to add some joined data.

Finally, another approach is to load the required data in the `_afterLoad()` method doing a separate select (as compared to a join):

```
// from Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page_Collection::_afterLoad()
protected function _afterLoad()
{
    if ($this->_previewFlag) {
        $items = $this->getColumnValues('page_id');
        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        if (count($items)) {
            $select = $connection->select()
                    ->from(array('cps'=>$this->getTable('cms/page_store')))
                    ->where('cps.page_id IN (?)', $items);

            if ($result = $connection->fetchPairs($select)) {
                foreach ($this as $item) {
                    if (!isset($result[$item->getData('page_id')])) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if ($result[$item->getData('page_id')] == 0) {
                        $stores = Mage::app()->getStores(false, true);
                        $storeId = current($stores)->getId();
                        $storeCode = key($stores);
                    } else {
                        $storeId = $result[$item->getData('page_id')];
                        $storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getCode();
                    }
                    $item->setData('_first_store_id', $storeId);
                    $item->setData('store_code', $storeCode);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return parent::_afterLoad();
}
```

This can be also done using an `*_load_after` event for collections or models.

Comment: Could you be more specific about where to find these examples in core?

Comment: Added examples to the answer.